# Table Cell Link in Mediawiki Markup

Tags: hyperlink, mediawiki, clickable

I'd like to make the entire cell in a MediaWiki table clickable, and not just the text inside it. I start off with this, for example:

```
{| style="width:400px;background-color:yellow;"
|-
|[[Article1|Tree]]||style="background-color:green"|[[Article2|Hat]]||[[Article3|Shoe]]
|-
|}
```

And, as expected, only the text is clickable. Can I rejig something to make it work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a TD clickable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326426/making-a-td-clickable)

Answer (score 2):

You can make the link fill upp the whole cell using CSS. Unless you turned that functionality off, use `MediaWiki:Common.css` to add your CSS:

```
td.clickablecell a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
```

and then add the class to your cell:

```
{| 
 |-
 |                         [[Article1|Tree]]
 | class="clickablecell" | [[Article2|Hat]]
 |                         [[Article3|Shoe]]
|}
```