# Clickable TD including the vertical space under the text

Tags: html, css

This is a variation of [James Donnelly's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317805/james-donnelly) answer to [a clickable link in a TD question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19326453/5611377).  I found a case where his answer doesn't completely work.

Here is the **[example in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ssimm/3crfg8L2/1/)**

I added vertical-align to td and lots of text to Parent1.

```
table.coolTable td {
        vertical-align:top;
        ...
```

The problem is that the empty space under *Parent2* is *not* clickable.  How do I get that part clickable too? Specifying fixed unit heights works but I don't want to constrain my table with fixed heights.

Thanks!

Comment: You want the gap between clickable elements to be clickable? Why?

Comment: Oh, I get what you mean, although I've had to resize the fiddle to see it: the `<a>` element doesn't expand to fit its container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to add `onclick` event listeners and a `cursor: pointer;` style to the `td`s.

```
HTML
<td onClick="document.location.href='#child'">
  ...
</td>

CSS
table.coolTable td {
  ...
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3crfg8L2/30/)

Comment: You get a Sesame Street Martian "yip yip yip yip yip" for this!